# Does createRoute method support lat/Lng in Mapquest?

Tags: android, dictionary, routes, mapquest

This is a question about Mapquest Android Maps API.

Does anyone know that the createRoute method is supporting lat/Lng or not in mapquest?

```
public void createRoute(java.lang.String from, java.lang.String to)
```

The document I found [here](http://developer.mapquest.com/content/mobile/android/documentation/api/com/mapquest/android/maps/RouteManager.html):

I have read the "Location Format Documentation" : [link](http://www.mapquestapi.com/common/locations.html)

It seems that createRoute method supports lat/Lng.

I tried to input lat/Lng a whole day but it returns me an error message only:

```
 Unable to create route. 
 Error: -1"
 Message:[null]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you still seeing this error message?  The [MapQuest Android Maps API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/android-maps-api) does support lat/lng input for routing.  Here is a sample request that uses lat/lng inputs:

```
private void displayRoute() {
RouteManager routeManager= new
RouteManager( this ); 
routeManager.setMapView( map ); 
routeManager.createRoute( "{latLng:{lat:37.765007,lng:-122.239937}}" , "Fremont, CA" );
}
```

Also, [The MapQuest Developer Network](http://developer.mapquest.com) has an [Android Maps API forum](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/forums/-/message_boards?_19_mbCategoryId=224714). It is also a good resource to check!

Comment: Thanks jharahush. I have checked the forum and tried to use your code in the MapQuest Android Maps API, but still seeing this error message

Comment: Can you post a code sample?  Like I said, the API does support lat/lng input, so maybe I can help if I see what your code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this

```
RouteManager routeManager = new RouteManager(this);
          routeManager.setMapView(map);
          routeManager.createRoute("37.002004,35.322998", "36.802687,34.632812");
```

or like this

```
RouteManager routeManager = new RouteManager(this);
          routeManager.setMapView(map);
          routeManager.createRoute("Any City Name", "Any City Name");
```

MapQuest is supporting this types